# How do I calculate confidence intervals for a non-normal distribution?

Tags: confidence-interval, mean

I have 383 samples that have a heavy bias for some common values, how would I calculate the 95% CI for the mean?  The CI that I calculated seems way off, which I assume is because my data does not look like a curve when I make a histogram.  So I think I have to use something like bootstrapping, which I don't understand very well.

Comment: One solution would be to use the asymptotic CI that makes use of the fact that the RV $\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{S/\sqrt{n}}$ has a limiting standard normal distribution. Your sample is reasonably large so it might make for a good approximation.

Comment: No, you will find really bad tail coverage in both tails of the confidence interval using that approach.  The average coverage might by good luck be OK but both tail error rates will be wrong.

Comment: What does "heavy bias for some common values" mean? Note that bias has a particular meaning in statistics; you should try to avoid it if you don't mean that. Do you simply mean "some particular values occur very often"? Can you show your calculations and some display or table of your data?

Comment: There is a good discussion in this paper [Wang ( 2001)  Confidence interval for the mean of non-normal data _Quality and reliability engineering international_ 17: 257-267](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/qre.400/abstract)

Answer (score 33):

Yes, bootstrap is an alternative for obtaining confidence intervals for the mean (and you have to make a bit of effort if you want to understand the method).

The idea is as follows:

1. Resample with replacement B times.
2. For each of these samples calculate the sample mean.
3. Calculate an *appropriate* bootstrap confidence interval.

Concerning the last step, there are several types of bootstrap confidence interval (BCI). The following references present a discussion on the properties of different types of BCI:

http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~zwp/teach/Stat-Comp/Efron_Bootstrap_CIs.pdf

http://www.tau.ac.il/~saharon/Boot/10.1.1.133.8405.pdf

It is a good practice to calculate several BCI and try to understand possible discrepancies between them.

In R, you can easily implement this idea using the R package 'boot' as follows:

```
rm(list=ls())
# Simulated data
set.seed(123)
data0 = rgamma(383,5,3)
mean(data0) # Sample mean

hist(data0) # Histogram of the data

library(boot) 

# function to obtain the mean
Bmean <- function(data, indices) {
  d <- data[indices] # allows boot to select sample 
    return(mean(d))
} 

# bootstrapping with 1000 replications 
results <- boot(data=data0, statistic=Bmean, R=1000)

# view results
results 
plot(results)

# get 95% confidence interval 
boot.ci(results, type=c("norm", "basic", "perc", "bca"))
```

Comment: The last step, calculate several, implies fishing for a CI you like from the result. You should decide on the kind of CI you want based on what they are beforehand.

Comment: @John Different CI have different properties. It is a good practice to check for possible discrepancies (and try to investigate the source of this). It is not about fishing for a convenient result.

Comment: Absolutely, but without such a description of the reason in your answer it "implies" fishing. And you're still not stating that it's critical to actually pick the CI you want first. I'm suggesting an update of the answer with some critical information for a naive questioner. It would be even better if you state which CI you generally prefer and why, or which one you prefer in cases like this one and why.

Comment: In this Khan Academy video:[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXZ2O1Lv-KE#t=229) He seems to be using a non-normal distribution, but uses "Sampling distribution of the sample mean" to get a normal distribution.  He's basically creating samples of various sizes and demonstrating that it forms a bell curve.  Is that basically a crude form of bootstrapping? or something entirely different, because it seems to get me the results I'm after.

Comment: @IhaveCandy: No. It demonstrates the Central Limit Theorem, i.e. how the sampling distribution of the mean tends to the normal, even for values following a very "unnormal" distribution. That is why the simple z confidence interval won't be much different to any other fancy solution, e.g. bootstrap.

Comment: @IhaveCandy Please see my comment above, Michael Mayer is making the same point.

Comment: Purely commenting to say that IhaveCandy is right - this solution will merely estimate the original CI calculation, which is justified by CLT. In fact, as your number of bootstrap samples goes to infinity, your CI estimate will trend towards your original CI estimate.

Comment: The CLT justifies nothing.  Confidence coverage can be way off in one or both tails when there is much asymmetry.

Answer (score 14):

Another standard alternative is to calculate the CI with the Wilcoxon test. In R

```
wilcox.test(your-data, conf.int = TRUE, conf.level = 0.95)
```

Unfortunately, it gives you the CI around the (pseudo)median not the mean, but then if the data is heavily non-normal maybe the median is a more informative measure.

Comment: Pythons scipy.stats.wilcoxon does not have the parameter conf.int and conf.level. Anyone knows how to solve this in Python?

Answer (score 6):

**You can just use a standard confidence interval for the mean:** Bear in mind that when we calculate confidence intervals for the mean, we can appeal to the central limit theorem and use the standard interval (using the critical points of the T-distribution), even if the underlying data is non-normal.  In fact, so long as the data is IID ([Independent and Identically Distributed](http://web.archive.org/web/20220602022331/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables)) and the distribution of the data has finite variance, the *distribution of the sample mean* with $n=383$ observations should be virtually indistinguishable from a normal distribution.  This will be the case even if the underlying distribution of the data is extremely different to a normal distribution.

Comment: could you please expand the meaning of IID?

Comment: @Andrei: IID is an acronym for [independent and identically distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables).

Comment: For a lognormal(0,1) distribution n=50,000 is not large enough to guarantee adequatey accurate confidence intervals.

Comment: @FrankHarrell: Based on my simulations, that does not appear to be true --- I get accurate intervals.  
```set.seed(1); n <- 50000; SIMS <- 10000; MEAN <- exp(1/2); ALPHA <- 0.05; RESULTS <- data.frame(sample.mean = rep(0, SIMS), CI.lower = 0, CI.upper = 0, capture = FALSE); for (i in 1:SIMS) { DATA <- rlnorm(n); INT  <- stat.extend::CONF.mean(x = DATA, alpha = ALPHA); RESULTS$sample.mean[i] <- mean(DATA); RESULTS$CI.lower[i] <- min(INT); RESULTS$CI.upper[i] <- max(INT); RESULTS$capture[i] <- ((MEAN >= RESULTS$CI.lower[i])&(MEAN <= RESULTS$CI.upper[i])); } sum(RESULTS$capture)/SIMS;```

Comment: I got terrible results for that - see if you can see the source of our differences - code is at https://hbiostat.org/bbr/htest.html#central-limit-theorem

Comment: @FrankHarrell: I've just run a few variations of both bits of code.  It appears that you get almost perfect coverage for lognormal(0,1), but start getting bad coverage when you bump up the sdlog parameter (presumably because this gives high skewness).  With ```sdlog = 1``` coverage is essentially perfect, with ```sdlog = 1.65``` it gets a little bad (though I wouldn't characterise it as terrible) and with ```sdlog = 5``` it gets terrible.

Comment: 1.65 gives terrible results in my view but agree with you otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

For log-normal data, [Olsson (2005)](http://jse.amstat.org/v13n1/olsson.html) suggests a 'modified Cox method'

If $X$ is log-normally distributed and $\rm{E}(X) = \theta$, the a confidence interval for $ \log(\theta)$ is:

$$
\bar{Y} = \frac{S^2}{2} \pm t_{df}\sqrt{\frac{S^2}{n} + \frac{S^4}{2(n-1)} }
$$

Where $ Y = \log(X)$, the sample mean of $Y$ is $\bar{Y}$ and the sample variance of $Y$ is $S^2$.  For df, use n-1.

An R function is below:

```
ModifiedCox <- function(x){
  n <- length(x)
  y <- log(x)
  y.m <- mean(y)
  y.var <- var(y)

  my.t <- qt(0.975, df = n-1)

  my.mean <- mean(x)
  upper <- y.m + y.var/2 + my.t*sqrt(y.var/n + y.var^2/(2*(n - 1)))
  lower <- y.m + y.var/2 - my.t*sqrt(y.var/n + y.var^2/(2*(n - 1)))

 return(list(upper = exp(upper), mean = my.mean, lower = exp(lower)))

}
```

Repeating the example from Olsson's paper

```
CO.level <- c(12.5, 20, 4, 20, 25, 170, 15, 20, 15)

ModifiedCox(CO.level)
$upper
[1] 78.72254

$mean
[1] 33.5

$lower
[1] 12.30929
```

Comment: is there a test for log normality?

Comment: try goft::lnorm.test

Comment: Link to paper is dead.

Comment: Confidence Intervals for the Mean of a Log-Normal Distribution
Ulf Olsson
Swedish University of Agricultural Sciences
Journal of Statistics Education Volume 13, Number 1 (2005), jse.amstat.org/v13n1/olsson.html