# What are meaningful ways to interpret Monte Carlo-simulated non-normal data?

Tags: probability, distributions, confidence-interval, variance, monte-carlo

My question relates to [Confidence Interval (CI) calculation of Monte Carlo-simulated non-normal data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/264050/confidence-interval-ci-calculation-of-monte-carlo-simulated-non-normal-data?noredirect=1&lq=1)

As answers and comments to that question show the confidence interval for the given distribution obtained by bootstrapping is very small and, to me, doesn't seem to describe the distribution very well.

Let's say I have a distribution of K that depends on 4 parameters a,b,c,d, all of which are following a uniform distribution. In addition I have limiting constraints on a and the resulting PDF is shown in the figure [image]

My question is: What meaningful statistical measures can I calculate for this distribution (mean, variance, standard deviation, confidence intervals?) and what would be the right approach to do that?